# R is the set of complex polynomials in one variable such that f(0) = f(1). Show that R is a finitely generated C-algebra. Describe Spec(R).

Tags: abstract-algebra

> We have that $R$ is the set of complex polynomials $f$ in one variable such that $f(0) = f(1)$. Show that $R$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb C$-algebra. Describe $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$.

I have assumed that $f(z) =a_0 + a_1z + a_2 z^2 +\dots+ a_n z^n$. By $f(0) = f(1)$, we have $a_0 = a_0 + a_1 +\dots + a_n.$ Then $a_1 +\dots+ a_n = 0$.

$R= <z^2 - z; z^2 - z +1; - z^2 - z +1>$
Then, we take $f$ in $R$. We should show that there exists $A;B;C$ such that  $a_z^2 + b_z +c = A(z^2 - z) + B(z^2 - z +1)+ C.(- z^2 - z +1)$.
Note that $a =-b$. Because we have that $f(1) = f(0)$, then $a+b+c = c$ and $a+b = 0$.

What should I do next?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

Such a polynomial is of the form $z(z-1)P + c$ for some polynomial $P$ and some constant $c\in\mathbb C$.

Thus to prove that $R$ is finitely generated, it suffices to find a family of polynomials that generate every $z^n(z-1)$ for $n\ge 1$.

I claim that $R$ is generated by $1$, $z(z-1)$ and $z^2(z-1)$.

Indeed for $n\ge 3$, $z^n(z-1)= z^{n-2}(z-1)\times z(z-1) + z^{n-1}(z-1)$, which allows a proof by induction.

To find the spectrum of $R$, we make the following observation: the subset $I_\alpha$ of $R$ consisting of polynomials vanishing at a point $\alpha\notin\{0, 1\}$ is a prime ideal. What's more the set of polynomials vanishing at $0$ and $1$ is also a prime ideal. This gives the intuition that $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ is $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb C[X])$ pinched in such a way that $0$ and $1$ become the same point.

Comment: If the product of two polynomials vanishes at $\alpha$, then one of them vanishes at $\alpha$. Algebraically, elements of $I_\alpha$ are of the form $z(z-1)P-\alpha(\alpha-1)P(\alpha)$.